# SUMIFS with comparisons to relative cells

Tags: numbers

(This is somewhat similar to [How do I reference a cell from within a "...IF"-type function condition string?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341871/how-do-i-reference-a-cell-from-within-a-if-type-function-condition-string) and [SUMIF statement with two different conditions (Text based and checkbox)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306865/sumif-statement-with-two-different-conditions-text-based-and-checkbox))

I have a formula on one sheet like the following:

```
=SUMIFS($Amount,$Date,">=01/01/2017",$Date,"<02/01/2017",$Key,"=IN:ALI*")
```

Where `$Amount`, `$Date`, and `$Key` reference specific columns on another sheet in the same file.
This works (yay)

Unfortunately, I have to copy and edit the formula for each column (and across all rows, since each row has a different string at the end as part of the condition). I want to make it easier to copy/paste this formula across multiple columns on the first sheet such that I'd get something like:

```
column-A: =SUMIFS($Amount,$Date,">=01/01/2017",$Date,"<02/01/2017",$Key,"=IN:ALI*")
column-B: =SUMIFS($Amount,$Date,">=02/01/2017",$Date,"<03/01/2017",$Key,"=IN:ALI*")
...
column-K: =SUMIFS($Amount,$Date,">=11/01/2017",$Date,"<12/01/2017",$Key,"=IN:ALI*")
...
```

So, I added a row so that near the top of each column (below headers / before data) I entered dates, e.g.:

```
A3: 01/01/2017
B3: 02/01/2017
...
```

The plan being to replace the hard-coded strings in my formula with cell refrences (e.g.: **A$3**, **B$3**, etc.), but I cannot seem to figure out a way to plug them into the formula in a manner that will allow them to update automatically/correctly when pasted into subsequent columns.

I tried `">=A$3"` and `"<B$3"` - but the '**A**' and '**B**' don't get updated when the formula is copied from cell `A4` to `B4`.

I tried `">=", A$3` ... `"<", B$3` - but I get a syntax error.

I tried `">=" A$3` ... `"<" B$3` - but that too gets a syntax error

Is there a way to do this?

(note: If I put all the formulas into a text-editor to do query-replaces on the date strings, I still have to click into each cell to paste them, otherwise the formulas end up as text-strings rather than formulas - if there's a good way around that I'd like to know too)

After various Q&A's and design morphing, this ended up as: [AppleScript Numbers: Process data from Quicken](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250487526?page=1)

Comment: I am a little confused by the point of your last sentence linking to the Apple Discussions page? How does this relate to your question?

Comment: I directed most of my questions regarding what I was trying to do to the Apple Discussions forums - and the post includes links to all the prior posted questions I had. It turns out there IS a way to do what I originally wanted: `=SUMIFS($Amount,$Date,">=" & A$3,$Date,"<" & B$3,$Key,"=IN:ALI*")` The trick being to use '`&`' to concatenate the comparison operator string and the cell-reference.

Comment: In Numbers 12.1 on macOS 11 Big Sur when using an operator within quotes, then the ampersand as a string concatenation operator and then the cell reference in the format LetterNumber works e.g. `">=" & B4`

Comment: The use of '&' is something I learned (later) in Google Sheets [too].
But thanks for following up on this as you never know when someone else will run into a similar issue.